# The command top -b -n 1| grep Cpu always returns the same value

Tags: linux, shell, grep

When I run the command `top -b -n 1| grep Cpu`, it always returns the same values:

```
Cpu(s): 0.3%us, 0.3%sy, 0.0%ni, 99.4%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st
```

but when I remove the `-n 1` part, the results start with

```
Cpu(s): 0.3%us, 0.3%sy, 0.0%ni, 99.4%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st
```

and then the subsequent values are different.

Any reason for this? How can I get different values?

Comment: Did you look up what the `-n 1` option does? If you did the answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `top` man page:

```
   The top command calculates Cpu(s) by looking at  the  change  in
   CPU  time  values between samples. When you first run it, it has
   no previous sample to compare to, so these  initial  values  are
   the percentages since boot. It means you need at least two loops
   or you have to ignore summary output from the first loop.   This
   is  problem  for  example  for  batch  mode. There is a possible
   workaround if you define the CPULOOP=1 environment variable. The
   top  command  will  be  run  one  extra hidden loop for CPU data
   before standard output.
```

Comment: But this info is mentioned in bugs section and not in the primary section.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you define option `-n max` will let top do `max` iterations. If you gave `1`, you will only get the data from 1 iteration. And get of course the single line data.

I don't know if how would you use the output. `top -b -n x|grep Cpu` could give different output depends on the version of `top` E.g. on my Archlinux, the output of `top -b -n 1 |grep Cpu` is:

```
kent$ (master|…) top -b -n 1 |grep Cpu
%Cpu0  :  12.7/4.1    17[|||||||||||                                                    ]
%Cpu1  :  69.9/17.3   87[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||        ]
%Cpu2  :  69.0/19.2   88[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||        ]
%Cpu3  :  68.1/18.0   86[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||         ]
```